# Using a QR Code within firewalls

Tags: qr-code, firewall

I want to have employees access meeting info (time, date, location, etc) via a QR code, however the info is stored within our corporated firewalls. I was thinking maybe I could have the QR code do something other than redirect to a website (since I can't make the info public), but I'm stumped for an alternative. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can put up a public website that does a 301 redirect to your internal website; for outsiders the second host name simply would't resolve.

Comment: how would that get them thru the firewall?

Comment: I assume your employees are inside the firewall, that is where employees normally are. The goal of the firewall is to keep non-employees out, not to keep employees in.

Comment: sorry for any confusion i'm providing, just unclear how a url redirect to an internal site wouldn't have the same authenication/security issues?

Comment: @user3585314: Because the firewall does not even **see** the redirect?

Comment: AH! so this assumes that the external and internal sites are hosted on related servers? Unfortunately, in our case, they are segregated.

Comment: No, it does not assume that. I can set up a server that redirects to stackoverflow.com, and I don't need anything for that on the SO side.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll reach out to our IT dept